# Grunt can't run because: Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I use the same project for two machines. I can use Grunt on my iMac with `npm 1.4.28` and can't run Grunt with my other machine `npm -v 2.5.1`

How can I revert my version of npm back to previous version? What if that particular version is not available?

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess and say that it's not npm that is the issue, but rather node. What does `node --version` spit out on the two boxes?

Comment: I had a similar issue that was node related, I use nvm to change the version quickly and easily (which also changes node version)  I detailed more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28572926/1258242

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what steveax in his comment answered is probably right!

but to answer your question, the crazy stuff about npm is that you can use npm itself to change the version:

```
$ npm install -g npm@1.4.28
```

Answer (score 1):

So @steveax was correct, it was a compatibility issue. A few other people experienced the same thing. The repository author issued a great solution, though I would like to see the module and npm latest versions be compatible. But this works now:

On Linux or Mac:

```
NPM install -g n
n 0.10.33
```

On Windows:

```
npm install -g nvmw
nvmw install v0.10.33
nvmw use v0.10.33
```

Comment: also, if you are doing so in the terminal, you may need to close the terminal and reopen...